# Android app time delay on 5.0+ devices

Tags: android, delay, android-5.0-lollipop, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My app is taking 10-12 sec delay while first load on 5.0+ devices, 4.4 or below devices does not have this problem.
I have added a log message in Application class onCreate method but it is also called after 10-12 sec seconds.
I have tried multidex enable false, minify enabled true but does not make any difference. 
I have found one thing, when we clear cache and data from app info activity, then it again delay while loading and my app is taking around 10mb of cache and 5 mb of data which is higher than usual.
How to address this problem? I have not find this type of issue on net or stackoverflow

Comment: Are you using instant run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens when you enable Instant Run in Android Studio. Try disabling instant run and check.
It happens only in debug builds