# Lauch screen showing white screen in android for too long at start up

Tags: android, apk

My problem is that every time i used to launch my app for the very first time. It showed a white screen for at-least 40 secs which was obviously too long than i learned about APK Analyzer in android studio. So i used it and i saw that libs folder was taking 93% of total size so i tried to remove all non used libraries and checked . The size became 74% of total app and i also saw a decrease of 20 secs in launch time but 22 secs is still a lot. I don't know how to solve this. Even if i show splash screen 22 secs wait is still a lot.
Sorry i am on other laptop so i can't show anything and i am just showing 2 buttons on startup so start screen can't be an issue. Can some one please help me solve this or atleast bring startup time to below 10 secs. Thank you :)

Comment: Which android studio you are using?

Comment: i don't remember the version , maybe 2.2 but i am pretty sure it's fully updated

Comment: I have faced same problem. Solutions:-
1. disable Instant run
2. Generate Signed apk
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430811/android-app-time-delay-on-5-0-devices]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to File -> Setting -> Build,Execution, Deployment-> Instant Run

uncheck the Enable instant run if it is checked, then run the project and let me know.

Comment: thank you :)
Worked. May i know the reason why?
I mean see now that when i used to load first time the app the size in preference was already 9 mb without doing anything. But when i disable it the app data is only 172 kb

Comment: Please check the link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run. You will find all the reason why it is so.. 
"Although your first build may take longer to complete, Instant Run pushes subsequent updates to your app without building a new APK, so changes are visible much more quickly."

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem try disabling instant run. The setting can be accessed by going into

File > Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run

Uncheck the Checkbox, then re-build the project